# Get free disk space with df to just display free space in kb?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cut, linux-disk-free

I'm trying to output the amount of free disk space on the filesystem `/example`.

If I run the command `df -k /example` I can get good information about available disk space in kb but only by  being human and actually looking at it.

I need to take this data and use it somewhere else in my shell script. I initially thought about using `cut` but then my script wont be portable to other disks as free disk space will vary and cut will not produce accurate results.

How can I get output of just the free disk-space of example in kb?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To get the output of `df` to display the data in kb you just need to use the `-k` flag:

```
df -k
```

Also, if you specify a filesystem to `df`, you will get the values for that specific, instead of all of them:

```
df -k /example
```

---

Regarding the body of your question: you want to extract the amount of free disk space on a given filesystem. This will require some processing.

Given a normal `df -k` output:

```
$ df -k /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        7223800 4270396   2586456  63% /
```

You can get the `Available` (4th column) for example with `awk` or `cut` (previously piping to `tr` to `squeeze-repeats` (`-s`) for spaces):

```
$ df -k /tmp | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
2586456
$ df -k /tmp | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
2586456
```

As always, if you want to store the result in a variable, use the `var=$(command)` syntax like this:

```
$ myUsed=$(df -k /tmp | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')
$ echo "$myUsed"
2586456
```

Also, from the [comment by Tim Bunce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703621/get-free-disk-space-with-df-to-just-display-free-space-in-kb/19703644#comment43896106_19703644) you can handle long filesystem names using `--direct` to get a `-` instead, so that it does not print a line that breaks the engine:

```
$ df -k --direct /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
-                7223800 4270396   2586456  63% /
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate you taking the time to give me an answer rather than just down vote like the others :( +1 for you!

Comment: Yes I tried too but the site is telling me I need to wait another 10 minutes to accept an answer.

Comment: You can use `cut` instead of `awk` in this case. No need to use a tank to kill a fly :)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann yes, I agree, maybe I like `awk` too much :D Updated with `cut` version, although it needs an extra pipe to squeeze the spaces.

Comment: Yes but wouldnt this take away portability? Because the length of the free disk-space could greatly vary on different file systems. So using cut would not accurately capture it unless I knew the exactly beginning and end index of the third arg. If theres a way to do this I'd love to know how!

Comment: oh you can specify the arg to cut with -f flag. I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: The `tail -1` then counting fields isn't safe because `df` may wrap put a newline after the filesystem name if it's long (e.g., for me `/dev/mapper/vg_1-lv_root`). A workaround is to use the `--direct` option which reports the filestem as `-`.

Comment: The question asks for 'free space' but the answer here reports the use space. Fix by using field 4 instead of field 3.

Comment: If the script is just trying to get a rough figure then try `--block-size=1G` to work in smaller GB values rather than very large KB values

Comment: @TimBunce thanks a lot for the valuable comments. Just updated accordingly!

Answer (score 14):

You can use stat(2) command to display free blocks and also to find out how large each block is, e.g.

```
stat -f --printf="%a %s\n" /
```

will display number of free blocks (%a) on a given file system (/) followed by a block size (%s). To get size in kB, you can use bc(1) command as in the following example:

```
stat -f --printf="%a * %s / 1024\n" / | bc
```

Finally, to put this into a variable is just a matter of using backtick substitution (or $() as in the first answer):

```
SOMEVAR=`stat -f --printf="%a * %s / 1024\n" / | bc`
```

Comment: Nice! Can also be easily used in a bash script, e.g. `if [[ $( stat -f --printf="%a*%s" $PWD ) -lt "1*1024**3" ]]; then echo "Less than 1G free"; fi`

Comment: This works on RHEL5, RHEL6 and also on my Ubuntu. Nice work.

Comment: Please suggest a change to return the value in MB. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Show interesting columns only

```
 df /example --total -k -h  --output=source,avail
```

- --total = grand total at the end
- -k = block size 1K
- -h = human readable
- --output=[FIELD_LIST] column list to show separated by ","

Not totally standard (I have seen --output is available at least on Ubuntu and RHEL), in this case Awk and others just to remove columns are not necessary.

Comment: `--output` is also available in RHEL.

Answer (score 9):

This is another solution:

```
df --output=avail -m /example | tail -1
```

output:

> 6415

Comment: Your solution can be further modified to `df --output=avail -m /example | tail -1 | tr -d ' '` to remove the space in front of the output.

Comment: This is nice because it provides a purely numerical value.

Comment: The free space returned by "df --output=avail -m /example | tail -1" is different from when you run the command "df /example"

Answer (score 0):

i created small script which will fetch the filesystem used space and will convert the total used space size in GB.

```
df -Th | grep -vE "tmpfs|nfs|boot|overlay|vfat|cifs"| awk '{print $4}'|sed 's/.$//'| grep -vw "^Use"| paste -s -d+|bc
```