# how to reliably get size of available disk space in unix

Tags: shell, unix, linux-disk-free

I tried this by typing  `df -k .`, I get the following:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       16512936 8650196   7023932  56% /
```

I tailed the last statement and gwt 4th block . 
but if file system name is long ,then

`df -k .`

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_vomesx6vm24-lv_root
                      51606140   1963476  47021224   5% /
```

is failing to get fouth block as fourth block is 5% . How to get available space in any situation ?

Comment: If you want in gbs or mbs then use df -m or df -g. see man df

Comment: what i am doing is tailing the last line and then extracting the fourth field(available),but problem is if file system name is long say,/dev/dfdsfidfidfdfdf then what unix do is print the details on new line ,thus it giving me 56% as a output

Comment: how to get exact available disk space only in any situation ?

Comment: Niraj: Since your problem is long device name causing df to fail to print in correct/readable format, I suggest you change the title and the descriptions.  And I suggest you give an example, OR do you mean the printing you shown above is missing /dev/dfdsfidfidfdfdf?  Please show us the results with your long device name.

Comment: df -k .
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_vomesx6vm24-lv_root
                      51606140   1963476  47021224   5% /

Comment: df -k .
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on/dev/mapper/vg_vomesx6vm24-lv_root
                      51606140   1963476  47021224   5% /

Comment: Pretty related: [Get free disk space with df to just display free space in kb?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19703621/1983854)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are exactly asking for, but you can tell df to show just what you need, eg.:

```
$ df -k --output=used /dev/mapper/vg_crypto-lv_root
    Used
28287028
```

Search for `FIELD_LIST` in df manpage for the details.

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
df -P|awk '{print $4}'
```