# Why does the output of df -m $PWD|awk {'print $4'} differ in different versions of RHEL

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rhel

I am writing a script to check for a few things before installing a package. I need to check how much free space the filesystem containing the $PWD has. I wrote and tested the script on RHEL 7.0. I used `df -m $PWD|awk {'print $4'}` to get the available free space. This works fine for RHEL 7.0.  But in RHEL 6.4 and 7.1, this does not return the free space in MB, but the free % available space on the filesystem. Visually they look the same. I see that the version of the `df` command is different from `df --version`. This script is to be used across a large variety of RHEL systems. What can be a workaorund to this?

Comment: I believe you already answered or at least partially answered your own question. Both the `df` and `awk` are going to be different versions. Clearly this method of getting free space is unreliable. Maybe try searching for a more general question on SO, such as "bash get free space". Also maybe try some of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703621/get-free-disk-space-with-df-to-just-display-free-space-in-kb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-P` with `df` command

> -P, --portability
>
> use the POSIX output format

```
df -m -P $PWD| awk {'print $4'}
```